# c++ get a static copy of a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this callback function:

```
if (FAILED(hr = g_lpDIDeviceJoystick->EnumEffectsInFile(FileConvert, EnumAndCreateEffectsCallback, NULL, DIFEF_INCLUDENONSTANDARD)))
    return hr;


BOOL CALLBACK FFBack::EnumAndCreateEffectsCallback(LPCDIFILEEFFECT pDIFileEffect, VOID* pvRef)
{
    STRUCT_EFFECTINFO EffectInfo;

    EffectInfo.GuidEffect = pDIFileEffect->GuidEffect;
    EffectInfo.lpDiEffect = pDIFileEffect->lpDiEffect;

    VectEffectInfo.push_back(EffectInfo);

    return DIENUM_STOP;
}


// Create all effect from vector
if (VectEffectInfo.size()>0)
    for (int i=0;i< VectEffectInfo.size();i++)
        if (FAILED(hr = g_lpDIDeviceJoystick->CreateEffect(VectEffectInfo[i].GuidEffect, VectEffectInfo[i].lpDiEffect, &g_lpdiEffect, NULL)))
            return hr;
```

The problem is that the static vector 'VectEffectInfo' don't keep the value of 'lpDiEffect' after exit to the function 'EnumAndCreateEffectsCallback' becouse this is pointer.

The vector is declared as static in the file ForceFeedback.h (public) inside the class:

```
class FFBack
{

public:


    struct STRUCT_DEVICEINFO
    {
        GUID guidInstance;
        std::string tszProductName;
    };

    struct STRUCT_EFFECTINFO
    {
        GUID GuidEffect;
        LPCDIEFFECT lpDiEffect;
    };

    static vector<STRUCT_EFFECTINFO> VectEffectInfo;
```

After exit to this function the value 'lpDiEffect' will change automatically and Unfortunately change also the vector (becouse to vector point to a pointer).

So I need a easy way to keep static copy of 'pDIFileEffect->lpDiEffect' that I can use outside this function 'EnumAndCreateEffectsCallback' like in my case.

So I have used a vector in this case but I don't sure if it is necessary becouse the function seem call only one time (each time return a vector of only one row).

Here the full fucntion:

```
BOOL CALLBACK FFBack::EnumAndCreateEffectsCallback(LPCDIFILEEFFECT pDIFileEffect, VOID* pvRef)
{
    STRUCT_EFFECTINFO EffectInfo;

    EffectInfo.GuidEffect = pDIFileEffect->GuidEffect;
    EffectInfo.lpDiEffect = pDIFileEffect->lpDiEffect;

    VectEffectInfo.push_back(EffectInfo);

    return DIENUM_STOP;
}



    HRESULT FFBack::PlayFileEffect(int Gain, std::wstring FileName) {
      LPCWSTR FileConvert = FileName.c_str();
    
      HRESULT hr;
    
      VectEffectInfo.clear();
    
      LF::Log_Update("init", true);
    
      // Assign all file effect to a vector
      if (FAILED(hr = g_lpDIDeviceJoystick -> EnumEffectsInFile(FileConvert, EnumAndCreateEffectsCallback, NULL, DIFEF_INCLUDENONSTANDARD)))
        return hr;
    
      if (VectEffectInfo.size() > 0)
        for (int i = 0; i < VectEffectInfo.size(); i++)
          if (FAILED(hr = g_lpDIDeviceJoystick -> CreateEffect(VectEffectInfo[i].GuidEffect, VectEffectInfo[i].lpDiEffect, & g_lpdiEffect, NULL)))
            return hr;
    
      if (FAILED(hr = g_lpdiEffect -> Start(1, 0)))
        return hr;
    }
```

After a small analisys at debug I can confirm that inside the function 'EnumAndCreateEffectsCallback': the value of VectEffectInfo[0].lpDiEffect is corrent. Outside the function the value of VectEffectInfo[0].lpDiEffect is changed and incorrect and the method 'g_lpDIDeviceJoystick->CreateEffect' return a error.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Isn't the simple answer not to use pointers? Copy the objects concerned instead of saving pointers. Hard to give a fuller answer without seeing the definitions and declarations of everything involved.

Comment: the Vector is not a pointer (i have added more info), but "pDIFileEffect->lpDiEffect" is a pointer. However I think this is the problem becouse after exit to the function the Vector in the field 'lpDiEffect' report a different value. I suspect the reason is becouse is a pointer.